# Open source license that requires attribution as a link at bottom of website

Tags: web-applications, open-source, licensing

I'm writting a php toolkit. I would like an open source license that requires a link at the bottom of page that says something like powered by toolkitName and links to my page that contains the source code and documentation. What license would have this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sonds like a creative commons ( http://creativecommons.org/choose/ ). you may as well write your own license specifying this. qquoting:

"With a Creative Commons license, you keep your copyright but allow people to copy and distribute your work provided they give you credit — and only on the conditions you specify here. "

EDIT: wanted to check first. the BSD license might apply as well. from ( http://www.opensource.org/licenses/bsd-license.php ):

"Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions are met:

Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution."

Comment: from what I have read on other post I heard the CC isn't meant for code. If you disagree please explain. As for the BSD they did have an "advertisement clause" which is similar to what I'm looking for however this was removed from the BSD license.

Comment: it is true that the creative commons was thought mostly for books, papers, etc. but it can be applied to software as well (you do not want to restrict the use, but on the contrary, permit distribution but retaining a copyright notice, this is why you can apply CC in your specific case). the bsd license (versions 2, and 3) do mantain the copyright i quoted. see: http://www.opensource.org/licenses/BSD-3-Clause

Comment: Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.

Comment: copy paste from cc ffaq<br />We do not recommend it. Creative Commons licenses should not be used for software. We strongly encourage you to use one of the very good software licenses which are already available. We recommend considering licenses made available by the Free Software Foundation or listed at the Open Source Initiative. Unlike our licenses, which do not make mention of source or object code, these existing licenses were designed specifically for use with software. Furthermore, our licenses are not compatible with the GPL, the most frequently used free software license.

Comment: it is not recommended because you are not licensing the product itself. you just state on how the work can be used/redistributed. but that's about it. "You should be aware that Creative Commons licenses only affect your rights under copyright. You are not licensing your trademark or patent rights, if any, when you apply a CC license to your work." subtle different, but if you're not concerned about licesing the product itself (but just that the users honor the copyright), it can be applied

Answer (score 0):

This is the best I have found myself. It's attribution isn't as specific as i'd like but it will do.

Open Source Initiative OSI - The Attribution Assurance

http://www.opensource.org/licenses/AAL